# python s3 upload file memory overflow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I need to upload 400,000 files to s3 storage, the code written in python, the memory keeps getting larger during the upload process, I use ThreadPoolExecutor

```
def scan_directory(path):
    files_to_upload = []
    prefix='img/html2'
    file_count = 0

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            local_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            cPath = os.path.dirname(local_path).replace(path, '/').replace("\\", "/")
            cos_path = prefix + cPath + file
            files_to_upload.append((local_path, cos_path))
            file_count += 1
    
    print(f"cout: {file_count}")
    return files_to_upload

def upload_files(files):
    total_uploaded = [0]  
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        num_threads = min(len(files), 20)
        file_chunks = [files[i:i+num_threads] for i in range(0, len(files), num_threads)]
        for chunk in file_chunks:
            executor.submit(upload_chunk, chunk, total_uploaded)

        while True:
            print(f"upload：{total_uploaded[0]}")
            time.sleep(10)

def upload_chunk(chunk, total_uploaded):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             endpoint_url=conn['endpoint'],
                             aws_access_key_id=conn['access_key_id'],
                             aws_secret_access_key=conn['access_key_secret']
                             )
    for file in chunk:
        s3_client.upload_file(file[0], conn['bucket'], file[1])
        
       
        total_uploaded[0] += 1
        os.remove(file[0])
    s3_client._request_signer._cleanup()  


files_to_upload = scan_directory('D:\\html')
upload_files(files_to_upload)
```

I limited the number of threads

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
```

and add

```
 while executor._work_queue.qsize() > 200:
                time.sleep(10)
                continue
```

but neither worked